# How to find Nth percentile with SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, percentile

I'll like to find Nth [percentile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile).

for example: table: htwt; columns: name, gender, height, weight

result:

```
| gender | 90% height | 90% weight |
| male   |        190 |         90 |
| female |        180 |         80 |
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

sqlite is not strong in analytical processing but if your data is not very large, you can try to emulate percentile with `ORDER BY`, `LIMIT 1` and a calculated `OFFSET`. Note that `OFFSET` is zero-based so you need to adjust it by one.

```
SELECT
  height AS 'male 90% height'
FROM table
WHERE gender='male'
ORDER BY height ASC
LIMIT 1
OFFSET (SELECT
         COUNT(*)
        FROM table
        WHERE gender='male') * 9 / 10 - 1;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "large" data? What range is the solution here good for in terms of # of rows of data in the table? And can you elaborate on the offset part on how you calculate that?

Comment: I have no idea about the data size range. If it works for you, good. The offset is for selecting the row at 90% of the data ordered by height - there's the other query for retrieving `male_count`.

Answer (score 10):

I needed multiple percentages (10, 20 ... 100%) and solved it with:

```
WITH p AS (SELECT height, NTILE(10) OVER (ORDER BY height) AS percentile
           FROM table
           WHERE gender = 'male')
SELECT percentile, MAX(height) as height
FROM p
GROUP BY percentile;
```

This solution requires SQLite 3.28.0 or later for the NTILE window function.

Comment: Note that it works only if the bins have all the same size or really close to that. For example, I divided my table into 100 bins using `ntile(100)`, ending up with 7 samples in bins 1-55 and 6 samples in bins 56-100. So all my top bins have only 6/7 (86%) the size of the bottom bins, which is quite a big difference.